# SQL: Inner join help for assessment

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

On my controlled assessment in school I'm stuck on this question:

Create, run, test, explain and demonstrate scripts to do the following:

1. Produce a list of all entries with the OCR exam board, showing:

   - the names of the students with entries
   - the subject names and level of entry for the exams the students are entered for.
2. Produce a list of all students, showing the students’ names, followed by the exams to be
   taken. This list should be presented in alphabetical order by the student’s last name.

In my code, I don't know how to join more than 2 tables with INNER JOIN, but if I try to the 'ON' statement doesn't want to work, I don't know how to solve this question.

`CREATE` tables and `INSERT` data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students
(
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
middle_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
UNIQUE (email)
);

INSERT INTO students (first_name,last_name,email,password,reg_date) VALUES 
("ex1","ex1.1","example1@gmail.com","11062001",'2009-12-04 13:25:30'),
("ex2","ex2.2","example2@gmail.com","ex123",'2015-02-12 15:20:45'),
("my name is jeff","21","kid","mynameis21kid@vine.com","yolo",'2014-09-21 14:15:25'),
("Mr.Right","Mr.Calvin","Mr.Hildfiger","Mr.misters@mister.com","mistermaster",'2015-06-04 19:50:35'),
("Bob","Dabuilda","bobthebuilder@fixit.com","BTBCWFI?",'2005-11-12 21:20:55');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects
(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (subject_id),
UNIQUE(subject_id)
);

INSERT INTO subjects (subject_name,level_of_entry,exam_board) VALUES 
("Chemistry","AS","OCR"),
("Biology","GCSE","AQA"),
("Music","GCSE","Edexcel"),
("English","A","OCR"),
("Physics","A","AQA"),
("Computing","GCSE","Edexcel"),
("French","A","AQA"),
("Maths","AS","OCR"),
("Product Design","GCSE","AQA"),
("History","AS","OCR");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries
(
entry_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
date_of_exam DATE NOT NULL,
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
PRIMARY KEY (entry_id)
);

INSERT INTO entries (date_of_exam, student_id, subject_id) VALUES 
('2015-05-31', 1, 6),
('2015-05-31', 2, 10),
('2015-01-21', 3, 3),
('2015-01-21', 4, 7),
('2015-09-13', 5, 1),
('2015-09-13', 2, 9),
('2015-12-06', 4, 8),
('2015-12-06', 1, 2),
('2015-04-01', 3, 5),
('2015-04-01', 5, 4);
```

And the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT entries.*, subjects.subject_name, subjects.level_of_entry
FROM subjects
    INNER JOIN entries,
               students ON entries.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
WHERE subjects.exam_board LIKE "OCR%";
```

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit (comma separated) `JOIN` syntax. It's too easy to make errors if you do. Stick to explicit JOIN all the way!!!

Comment: In what sense is this assessment 'controlled'?

Comment: @Strawberry http://www.ocr.org.uk/qualifications/by-type/gcse-related/controlled-assessment/ says "Controlled assessment is individual candidate work that is carried out in a supervised environment/classroom. This was introduced by the regulator to address some of the issues raised about coursework, such as plagiarism."

Comment: @ceejayoz Aren't we slightly undermining that objective?

Comment: @Strawberry I think so, yeah, but I'm not from the UK. Maybe you're allowed to prep in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the join condition right after the join to keep it simple and readable. As jarlh wrote, do not mix the explicit joins with the comma separated list. There is no need to do a like with pattern matching if you know the exact value you are looking for. Just use the = operator with the exact value.

```
SELECT *
FROM subjects
INNER JOIN entries ON entries.subject_id = subjects.subject_id --join 2 tables
INNER JOIN students ON entries.student_id=students.student_id --join the 3rd tables
WHERE subjects.exam_board = "OCR";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit `JOIN`'s, start now and never look back! Also use aliases to keep things neat.

```
SELECT e.*, su.subject_name, su.level_of_entry
FROM subjects su
INNER JOIN entries e ON e.subject_id = su.subject_id
INNER JOIN students st ON e.student_id = st.student_id 
WHERE su.exam_board LIKE "OCR%";
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you might need the code to look like is this:

```
select entries.*, subjects.subject_name, subjects.level_of_entry
from entries
join students on students.student_id = entries.student_id
join subjects on subjects.subject_id = entries.subject_id
where exam_board = 'OCR';
```

I hope this helps.